# Using COM DLLs with FSI

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

Is there a way within FSI that I can reference and use registered COM components?

In a normal .fs compiled program I can simply reference the component in question and then open the relevant generated namespace(s).  In a .fsx file, however, I can't seem to replicate this behaviour. I have tried using #r to reference the .dll directly, and I have tried using #I to point to the directory followed #r both with the library's "friendly" name and the file name, but nothing seems to work.

Are you only able to reference .NET assemblies from a .fsx?  I don't really want to have to write/gen a wrapper assembly.  I am hoping there might be a way to force FSI to take whatever steps the normal executable takes in order to provide the interop layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a reference to a COM component in Visual Studio, it invokes a tool to generate a wrapper (standard .NET assembly) and then references the wrapper.

If you want to reference COM from `fsx`, you'll need to generate the wrapper yourself (or find the one generated by Visual Studio?) The tool that generates the wrapper that is called `TlbImp.exe` (see [Type Library Importer on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I had suspected as much !

Comment: What you don't have to do this yourself anymore?