# Type reference error using F# interactive

Tags: matlab, f#, reference, assemblies, f#-interactive

I have a solution consisting of 2 projects:

- **Utilities** - This project contains type `MyMatlab` and references a COM (TLP) reference `Matlab Application (Version 7.11) Type Library`
- **LBM** - This project contains function `displayMyMatlab` which uses the `MyMatlab` type from the `Utilities` project and thus this project references `Utilities`

I create a `fsx` file containing:

```
 #r @".\bin\Release\LBM.dll"
 #r @".\bin\Release\Utilities.dll"
 LBM.displayMyMatlab()
```

and I get following error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 

--> Referenced 'D:\Olda\Bak\Projects\LBM\OldaConsortium\bin\Release\LBM.dll'


--> Referenced 'D:\Olda\Bak\Projects\LBM\OldaConsortium\bin\Release\Utilities.dll'



Lars_Slump_Post.fsx(45,21): error FS0074: The type referenced through 'Utilities.Matlab' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Utilities'.
>
```

What does it mean? When I do the same using an ordinary compiled project, it works just fine. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Tomas Petricek answered a similar question here: 
[Using COM DLLs with FSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407669/using-com-dlls-with-fsi)

I'm guessing you need to reference the generated wrapper dll before referencing your own dlls. The generated wrapper is normally named 'Interop.LibName.dll', in your bin folder.

Comment: @ Oldrich Svec - Have you tried reversing the references, i.e Utilities first, then LBM?